# Mini Search engine in Angular2 with Giphy API : how do I use components?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

So I just started programming Angular2 (not AngularJS). I followed this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/getting-started-with-angular-2-by-building-a-giphy-search-application , and got a result similar to: http://hitman666.github.io/giphy-search/ (source code at: https://github.com/Hitman666/GiphySearch_Angular2).

Except the gifs are an array in this model, and I want to make components from them, then maybe display a random one each time. I started playing with the code and made the component, but I'm not sure how to put it all together. It doesn't work anymore, but it would just like the tutorial by changing a few lines and ignoring the gif component. 
I just started programming in angulaire so I am open to ANY advice.

Here is the code I have:

app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { GiffComponent } from '../giff/giff.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Giphy';
  http: Http;
  gif:string;

  link = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q=';

    /*constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }*/
    constructor(gif:GiffComponent){

    }
  performSearch(searchTerm: HTMLInputElement): void {
    console.log(`User entered: ${searchTerm.value}`);
    var apiLink = this.link + searchTerm.value;

    this.http.request(apiLink)
        .subscribe((res: Response) => {
              this.gif = res.json().data;
              console.log(this.gif);
        });
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, HttpModule, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { GiffComponent } from '../giff/giff.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    GiffComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <h1>
    Application de recherche {{ title | uppercase }}!
  </h1>
  <input name="Rechercher" #searchTerm>

  <button (click)="performSearch(searchTerm)">Search</button>
<giff></giff>
  <br> 
  <div *ngFor="let j of giffs"> <img src="{{j.images.original.url}}"> </div>
</div>
```

-- Gif folder (for some reason I typed giff)

giff.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'giff',
  templateUrl: './giff.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./giff.component.css']
})
export class GiffComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() gif
  src: string;
  link = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q=';
    giffs = [];
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getGif(searchTerm) {
    return this.http.get('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=5927585945364280883a90015b9027cd&q=' + searchTerm + '&limit=1&lang=fr')
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.src='http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q=';
  }

}
```

giff.component.html

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'giff',
  templateUrl: './giff.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./giff.component.css']
})
export class GiffComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() gif
  src: string;
  link = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q=';
    giffs = [];
  constructor(private http:Http) { }

  getGif(searchTerm) {
    return this.http.get('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=5927585945364280883a90015b9027cd&q=' + searchTerm + '&limit=1&lang=fr')
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.src='http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q=';
  }

}
```

If you don't want to go through the trouble of looking at the source code of the tutorial, here is the former app.contents.ts with a layer of gifs that I changed (if I paste that back the app works).

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';


@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'Welcome to GiphySearch';
    link = 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q=';
    http: Http;
    giphies = [];

    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.http = http;
    }

    performSearch(searchTerm: HTMLInputElement): void {
        var apiLink = this.link + searchTerm.value;

        this.http.request(apiLink)
            .subscribe((res: Response) => {
                  this.giphies = res.json().data;
                  console.log(this.giphies);
            });
    }
};
```

Thank you VERY MUCH if you take the time to read that, and as I said, any kind of advice would be very appreciated :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: if this is your real api key for giphy i would suggest to remove it from a public place like stackoverflow